# Universal output device in R

Tags: r

Are there any universal output devices in R?

I'd like to have device which stores all plots and histograms while interpreter is running, doesn't make any side-effects like opening window or writing to file and has possibility to copy data to another device through `dev.copy` and `dev.print`.

For example:

```
plot(cars)
# writes data to device,
# it's possible to execute `dev.print(png, ...)` here and
# get valid picture

lines(lowess(cars))
# updates current device,
# it's also possible to execute `dev.print(...)` and get valid picture

plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi)
# writes data to new device,
# it's possible to execute `dev.print(...)` and
# get valid picture for second plot and 
# execute `dev.copy(...)` and get valid picture for the first plot
```

I'm running on Linux, but I'd prefer cross-platform solution.

Comment: Are you running on windows, mac or else? (please add it to the question)

Comment: @RHA The question has been updated.

Comment: Can you please explain why you need this? There might be alternative approaches.

Comment: @Roland I'm trying to understand how such functionality is implemented in R Studio, I thought there is some device in the interpreter.